# Stylesheet to verify if one any test failed for any of an xml document's node

Tags: xslt

Please help with the following:

I have an input file that is quite heterogeneous and big.

I need to run individual tests on individual nodes and in the end output a boolean value: did any test fail? or did they all pass?

Is there a good way to do that?

I've detailed bellow an example.

A simplified sample of input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Application>
      <PersonApplicants>
               <Person ApplicantType="Borrower" ApplicationType="Sole" >
                    <PersonName FirstName="Jane" Surname="Smith" />
                    <PersonalDetails CreditHistory="CleanCredit" YearsInCurrentProfession="12">
                        <Residency ResidencyStatus="Citizen" ResidencyCountry="Australia"/>
                    </PersonalDetails>
                </Person>
                <Person ApplicantType="Guarantor" ApplicationType="Sole" >
                    <PersonName FirstName="John" Surname="Smith" />
                </Person>
        </PersonApplicants>
      <CompanyApplicants>
        <Company ApplicantType="Guarantor" ApplicationType="Joint">
          <CompanyName CompanyName="C1" TradingName="C1" />
          <BusinessDetails YearsInBusiness="19" CreditHistory="CleanCredit" />
        </Company>
      </CompanyApplicants>
    </Application>
```

Run a series of individual tests on each node, and output at the end whether at least one of the test has failed or all have passed.

Output sample xml:

```
<TestResult>Failed</TestResult>
```

if any of the test failed 
or

```
<TestResult>Passed</TestResult>
```

if all tests passed.

This is a sample of what i was trying to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <TestResult>
            <xsl:variable name="fail_test">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Application" />
            </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- If any rule triggers/fails, output the following value "True".-->
                    <xsl:when test="$fail_test">True</xsl:when>
                    <!-- Otherwise putput the following value "False"-->
                    <xsl:otherwise>False</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </TestResult>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Application">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PersonApplicants"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CompanyApplicants"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="PersonApplicants">
    <!-- Test Rule 1 Have at least one Borrower, Person or Company.  -->
    <xsl:variable name="var1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//Person/@ApplicantType='Borrower' or //Company/@ApplicantType='Borrower'"><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="false()" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Test Rule 2 Only one applicant allowed for a Sole application, Person or Company. -->
    <xsl:variable name="var2">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Person/@ApplicationType='Sole'">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(//Person) + count(//Company) = 1"><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="false()" /></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
<!-- need a way to handle the results on all Person nodes -->
<!-- this is only in here as a placeholder for the correct code -->
        <!-- Test child nodes of Person Applicants, i.e Person nodes. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Person">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
<!--******************************************************************-->
            <!--the returned value of the template-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="not($var1 and $var2)" />
<!--******************************************************************-->
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
<!-- @ApplicantType LIXI 2.0 node Validation: is required -->
<xsl:variable name="var1">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not (@ApplicantType) or string(@ApplicantType) =''"><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="false()" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>


<!-- @PrimaryApplicant LIXI 2.0 node Validation: PrimaryApplicant is required when Applicant Type is Borrower -->
<xsl:variable name="var2">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not (@PrimaryApplicant) or string(@PrimaryApplicant) =''">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@ApplicantType='Borrower'"><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="false()" /></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="true()" /></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>


        <!--the returned value of the template-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="not($var1 and $var2)" />
<!--******************************************************************-->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest, from where you are would be

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <TestResult>
        <xsl:variable name="fail_test">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Application" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($fail_test,'false')" >Failed</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Passed</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </TestResult>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the end of your test sylesheet isn't well formed and `/xsl:if` should be `/xsl:choose`

Comment: Thank you, but the question was how do i get the variable value right, not how I  test the variable once i'd have it.
Corrected the mistake, ta.

Comment: If you modify the stylesheet as I suggest it will give the result that you requested; returning Failed if any individual test failed and Passed if they all passed. In what way is that different from your original question?

Comment: Understood what you meant now; I set off to get a boolean value at the top and test that, not a string containing the results of all tests. Thank you